# How to manage MediaPlayer.setVolume() + SeekBar to set it + device volume control

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, seekbar

As [recommended by the doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume(float,%20float)), I'd like to use the `setvolume()` method to control the volume of my `MediaPlayer`, but I'm a bit confused about how to manage it.

I'm setting the volume using a `SeekBar`, initialized to the current volume in the `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC` stream.

This makes sense when the user does not modify the device volume control, but when he does, I'm not sure what I should do, and I have several doubts:

- how is the `MediaPlayer` volume related to the device volume? Does the max value (1) set in `setVolume()` correspond to `mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)`
- if it's the case, the progress value of the `SeekBar` should be reset every time the device volume control is set, but then, what's the point of using `MediaPlayer.setVolume()` instead of [AudioManager.setStreamVolume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume(int,%20int,%20int))?
- what's the standard way of using `MediaPlayer.setVolume()` with a `SeekBar`?

```
private final static int MAX_VOLUME = 100;
private AudioManager mAudioManager; 
private SeekBar mVolumeControl;

mVolumeControl = (SeekBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.volume_control);
mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mVolumeControl.setMax(MAX_VOLUME);
mVolumeControl.setProgress(MAX_VOLUME*mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)/mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)); 
mVolumeControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(mVolumeControlChangeListener);

private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener mVolumeControlChangeListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        float volume = (float) (1 - (Math.log(MAX_VOLUME - progress) / Math.log(MAX_VOLUME)));
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 13):

`MediaPlayer.setVolume` sets the volume of that player as a percentage of the overall volume for that stream. It does not affect the stream volume. So if you want to set just that player's volume, set it to something between 0 and 1 (a fractional value representing the percentage) and let the user control the system volume separately by using the hardware volume controls. To hook up a `SeekBar`, you can scale it by a factor of 100 like you've done in your sample code, since `SeekBar` doesn't support fractional values. Oh, and one more thing for others' benefit (since you've already figured it out): the docs say "UI controls should be scaled logarithmically", which means that if you just set the volume without any scaling, the volume control will feel unnatural. Basically, halving the amplitude of the wave is NOT perceived by the human ear as "half the volume", so you need to scale logarithmically to make it feel more natural to the human ear, like you've done in your sample code.

If you do want to set the system volume for the given stream (and not just for the given player), you can use `AudioManager.setStreamVolume` with a value between 0 and the value returned by `AudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume`. But keep in mind that that one is generally a low-resolution volume control - `getMaxStreamVolume` usually returns a relatively low value - like 10 or 15, so you only have a few possible positions for the volume. This means that controlling the volume will not be as smooth as if you control the `MediaPlayer`'s volume directly. Also, obviously, setting the volume this way sets it for the entire system and affects all applications, which may not be what the user wants.

Comment: hey, this was really informative. Helped me figure out a solution to a prob I was stuck on. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to TodorK's answer.

What I did is I initially set the StreamVolume to Max, and let user control the SeekBar. Once they finished , I set the StreamVolume back to its original state. 
This allows the user to control the MediaPlayer volume, and does not effect other applicaitons.

First set the Stream to your desired one & Initialize AudioManager

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
audioManager = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Get the InitialVolume (so that you set it back to this once you're done) and set it to MaxVolume

```
final int initVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
final int maxVolume  = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,maxVolume, 0);
```

Do the AudioStuff in the onProgress part of the SeekBarChangedListener

```
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) 
        {
            float volume = (float) (1 - (Math.log(100 - progress) / Math.log(100)));
            mp.setVolume(volume, volume);
            mp.start();
        }
```

Once you're done, set it back to the initialVolume, so that the User doesnt get pissed off (in my case,im using an AlertDialog, so its in the onDismiss thing

```
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) 
        {
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,initVolume, 0);

            //Stop Playing the Song
            stopSong();             
        }
```

Also notice, I did the log stuff in the onProgress part

Comment: Hey, sorry about bother you, but I saw this your answer and I thought that maybe you could help me (If you don't mind). I posted my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322485/change-the-volume-of-a-specif-player-and-get-its-current-volume), I need to finish this project and only missing this 2 methods. I tried the mp.setVolume and works but just for a while, after the volume backs to normal again.
But set the progress like volume before show the seekbar I have no idea, 'cause if I use AudioManager I will get all players volume.
Please, if you could help me I'll thank.

Answer (score 1):

First make a seekBar in XML file. Then copy this code (`seekBar2` is the Id for the seekBar):

```
private final static int MAX_VOLUME = 100;
SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        float volume = (float) (1 - (Math.log(MAX_VOLUME - progress) / Math.log(MAX_VOLUME)));
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
});
```